# Unable to extracting data from JSONP

Tags: jquery, jsonp

If the following works:

`alert( data.query.results.tbody[1].tr[0].td[0].span.img.src );`

Why will this not work?

```
var image = data.query.results.tbody[1].tr;
alert( image[0].td[0].span.img.scr );
```

The second alert gives me:

`Undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix spelling `scr` to `src` :-)

```
alert( image[0].td[0].span.img.src );
```

Comment: @oshirowanen: Sometimes happens with everyone and hard to notice :)